# Knowing resulting URL for jquery ajax request?

Tags: jquery, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I'm using an jquery-ajax request to read information from a site in 2 steps. My problem is that the URL is "rewritten" by the server in the first request, and the second request must use the same URL to get the correct answer. Ie testing in a browser show the calls needs to be done as:

1. My ajax call to "http://www.aninfosite.com/givemeinfo.php?category=aaaaaaaa"
2. The reply comes from something looking like "http://www.aninfosite.com/**(S(ethypr55003qd145gwzzlqau))**/givemeinfo.php?category=aaaaaaaa"
3. My Second call must then be made to "http://www.aninfosite.com/**(S(ethypr55003qd145gwzzlqau))**/givemeinfo.php?category=aaaaaaaa"

How can I in step 2 know the "answering" "random" url?

The test ajax code I'm using now look as follows. I've tried all the different solutions I have found here on Stackoverflow as shown in the "alerts" below...

```
function konGetUrlHTML(sUrl,sPostField,sPostValue){
    alert("Debug: konGetUrlHTML");
    $.ajax({
        url: sUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: { sPostField: sPostValue },
        success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
            alert("Debug: konProcessUrlHTML");
            alert(this.url); // Returns original URL
            alert("Header: " + jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Location'));  // Return NULL
            alert(data);
        },
        complete: function(){
            alert("complete: " + this.url); // Returns original URL
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

The second call fails to return the correct result due to the missing "Url code". (Ie the sites processing starts from the beginning)

(The javascript is not running on the same site, but I have no cross site problems. It's running in PhoneGap. )

Anyone know a solution?

Thank you!

Koniak

Comment: I havew now verified that there is a redirect between the above steps 1 and 2. Here the header contains the "Location: /(S(ethypr55003qd145gwzzlqau))/givemeinfo.php?category=aaaaaaaa".

This means that in my tests above, the redirect has already taken place and thats the reason jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Location') returns NULL. Is it possible to make ha XMLhttpRequest WITHOUT automatically following the redirect? (If i get the redirection information page I would be able to read the header Location and manuallt adopt the URL...)

Comment: Two things I see that could solve this would be:
`(1.) Stop the xmlhttprequest from following the redirect.`  `(2.) Find a way to query ajax/xmlhttprequest of actual URL it was redirected to.`  Any ideas anyone? (Or does anyone know that this can't be done?)